# Yii2 : Arabic language filename not support in `addFromString` of ZipArchive

Tags: php, zip, yii2, php-ziparchive

I have used `ZipArchive` for creating zip. but i have problem with filename assign in **Arabic language** that is not supported.

I want to get filename like **21_بينل.pdf** but i getting **21_.pdf**.

I have refer following question.

[PHP ZipArchive non-English filenames return funky filenames within archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600843/php-ziparchive-non-english-filenames-return-funky-filenames-within-archive)

but still not working.

My sample code:

```
<?php
     $zip = new ZipArchive;
     $res = $zip->open('test.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);
     $fileName = $v->certificateLetter->fileName.'/'.$v->dslStu->stu_unique_id.'_'.'بينل';
     $zip->addFromString($fileName.'.pdf', $letterString);
     $zip->close();
?>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: add `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'he_IL.UTF-8');` at the top and check.

Comment: for example : `iconv('cp866', 'utf-8', $filename)`

Comment: use of `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'he_IL.UTF-8');` and `iconv('cp866', 'utf-8', $filename)` than i am getting filname like **21_????????.pdf**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP ZipArchive non-English filenames return funky filenames within archive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600843/php-ziparchive-non-english-filenames-return-funky-filenames-within-archive)

Comment: i have read above link but still not working. so its different que.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open('test.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);
$fileName = $v->certificateLetter->fileName.'/'.$v->dslStu->stu_unique_id.'_'.'بينل';
iconv('CP1256', 'utf-8', $fileName).PHP_EOL;
$zip->addFromString($fileName.'.pdf', $letterString);
$zip->close();
```

Comment: @GAMITG: you can check here regarding your language: http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

Comment: try this for arabic language: iconv('cp1256', 'utf-8', $fileName);   CP1256 for MS-ARAB WINDOWS-1256... updated in answer @GAMITG